# Where did i go wrong in limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

We were asked to find the limit of $(\frac{1}{x})^{\sin x}$. The following picture is the solution shown by our mentor. But I have a different approach.

[image]

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin x}=e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} ((\frac{1}{x}-1)\sin x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (1-x)\frac{\sin x}{x}}=e.$$
Both of the calculations look fine to me, where did I go wrong then?

Comment: In the first step, it should be $e^{\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x\ln \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$. You forgot the logarithm. Also, I'm not sure how you went from $\frac{1}{x}$ to $\frac{1}{x}-1$

Comment: Actually i am following the trick of this video,there wasn't any logarithm  https://youtu.be/JWbNK5T-V5Y

Comment: The minus one trick in that video is when the numerator and denominator of the thing being exponentiated, e.g. $5x+1$ and $3x+1$ in $\left(5x+1\over3x+1\right)^x$, have the *same degree*. In this problem, the numerator in $1/x$ is of degree $0$ while the denominator is of degree $1$, so the video's minus one trick doesn't apply. (Your question would make more sense if you included the link to the video in it and explained, in your own words, that it presents a minus-one trick for calculating certain limits.)

Comment: Could you please show me the proof for the trick?That way it will make me cautious not to make such mistakes any more.

Comment: Please try to avoid using images as the main content of your post.

Comment: The limit should also be 0+

Answer (score 4):

It's good to understand tricks instead of just blindly using them. I don't exactly understand the reasoning for the trick, but I believe it makes use of the taylor approximation of the logarithm centered around $1$ (i.e. when $|x-1|\ll 1$, $\ln x\approx x-1$)

Anyway, looking at all the examples in the video, I believe this trick only works when dealing with the $1^\infty$ indeterminate form and not the $\infty^0$ indeterminate form that your problem is dealing with. This makes sense as you would be applying the taylor approximation when the terms inside the natural log approach $1$. I'll add a proof if I can figure out one.

Well, I didn't prove it myself, but I found a [quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-evaluate-limits-of-1-infinify-form) that did. I'll just rewrite the proof. Let's say we want to compute $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ where $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=\infty$. Then we have
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to a} (1+(f(x)-1))^{g(x)(f(x)-1)\cdot \frac{1}{f(x)-1}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to a} \left((1+(f(x)-1))^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}\right)^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to a} e^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$

Comment: Yes, that's the correct intuition behind the trick. We can break it horrendously (and contradicting the claim in the beginning that it works for $x \to \text{anything}$) by taking one of the examples in the video and changing the limit point. E.g. $( \frac{1 + 5x^2}{1 + 3x^2} )^{1/x^2} \to 3/2$ as $x \to 1$, but the "trick" would suggest it is $e^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, if you have at your disposal the standard limits ${\sin x\over x}\to1$ and $x^x\to1$ as $x\to0$, then

$$(1/x)^{\sin x}=(1/x^x)^{\sin x/x}\to(1/1)^1=1$$

Comment: You were quicker. :-)

Comment: @trancelocation, more likely I had a head start. Great minds and all that.  ;-)

Comment: @BarryCipra I haven't a great mind...but I like also your short answerr :-D